# Search Table for Multiple Values and Return Corresponding Date in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to search a table sample shown below

**Crossing Type**             **Inspection Date**

```
Aqueduct            1/1/14      

South San Diego     1/2/14

Aqueduct            3/2/14

Railroad            3/2/14

Railroad            3/5/14

Aqueduct            4/14/14
```

From this table I am trying to search for the value "Aqueduct" and return the corresponding date. Unfortunately Vlookup doesn't work because it is only returning the initial date value and won't sort through the rest of my array for other values of "Aqueduct"

I've been searching the Web for a few hours and have found some decent ideas but none of which have worked.

Any help would be greatly Appreciated.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Where is your code so far? If it is not about programming, you are in the wrong site. Superuser.com helps with software questions.

Comment: So what date do you want to return? The latest date or the oldest? or is it conditional? Your question lack *specific* detail. Please revise and add relevant information on what exactly you want to achieve and what have you tried to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setup an **AutoFilter** on your columns.  Select *Aqueduct* for Column **A.**  Copy the visible rows and paste elsewhere.

See:

[AutoFilter](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter01.html)

If you want an easy formula solution, we can use a "helper column"

In **C2** enter:

=IF(A2="Aqueduct",1,"")

In **C3** enter:

=IF(A3="Aqueduct",1+MAX($C$2:C2),"")

and copy down.  This will supply unique, sequential IDs to the "good" rows.

Finally in **D2** enter:

=IFERROR(INDEX(B:B,MATCH(ROWS($2:2),C:C,0),1),"")

and copy down.  Format column **D** as *Date*

Here is an example:

[image: x]